# Match a words, which contains specific symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

It seems that i'm stuck with something simple, but I was unable to find quite similar question on stack.

Using `JavaScript/jQuery/regexp` I want to match a words that contains specific symbols in string .

I.e in given string `'check out mydomain/folder/#something'` if i run this kind of search with symbols `'folder/#'` it must return whole  `mydomain/folder/#something`.

In fact I want to use this to replace whole link in a string with some kind of widget button, but as those links are pretty specific (i.e i know that they will contain `folder/#`) using some kind of library for this task would be overkill.

Comment: what is source of strings? If these are element href's can simplify the issue

Comment: @charlietfl just a simple string in variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regexp you are looking for: `/[\w\/]*\/folder\/#[\w\/]*/`

```
var str = 'check out mydomain/folder/#something';
// returns ["mydomain/folder/#something"]
str.match(/[\w\/]*\/folder\/#[\w\/]*/)
```

---

Or for a more robust version or it: `/[\w\/\.]*\/folder\/#(?:[\w\/]|\.\w+)*/`

That last one will accept dots in the file names but ignore the last one.

For instance `'check out my.domain/foo/folder/#some.thing.'`will return `["my.domain/foo/folder/#some.thing"]`

Comment: That's almost it, regexp is frankly not my strongest side, tested this one but in the string with `http://` like `check out http://mydomain/folder/#something` it selects only `/mydomain/folder/#something` it seems that it does not include link fully, `http:/` is left behind. Pardon me that i did not included this in example in question, but can you possibly make a correction?

Comment: with a help of lucky randomness i figured out this regexp `/[\w\/\.\:]*\/folder\/#(?:[\w\/]|\.\w+)*/` now `http:` included. Is it right or i made  something terrible on par with devil summoning?

Comment: So I left off with `str.match(/[\w\/\.\:]*\/folder\/#(?:[\w\/]|\.\w+)*/g)` which returns handy array of all occurrences, and i can't see any caveats at the moment, therefore thank You, Your answer was extremely helpfull.

Comment: Yeah indeed I forgot to add the `:` character into the allowed ones, your correction seems perfect